# pdflatex.exe - .synctex not written properly

Tags: pdftex, forward-inverse-search

I am writing on an IEEE LaTeX project at Windows 8.1 using TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX version 2.9. Further I am using SumatraPDF as viewer to perform forward and reverseSearch while watching the output.

A few days ago, suddenly the output of the .synctex file is not working anymore. It is written as .synctex(busy), but not renamed at the end of the compilation process. Hence, forward and reverse search is not working. If I rename the file manually and remove the (busy)-addition, everything is working as expected.

The document is compiling without any errors or warnings, both in LaTeX and BibTeX. I am not using makeindex in this project. However, I find the following output:

```
pdflatex> Output written on "<filename>.pdf" (7 pages, 837267 bytes).pdflatex.exe: Windows API error 4350: This file is currently not avaiable for use on this computer.

pdflatex.exe: Data: <filename>.synctex
```

These are the exact versions I currently use:

- pdfTeX, version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14
- MiKTeX 2.9
- LaTeX2e 2011/06/27
- BibTeX 0.99d

Can someone tell me, why the .synctex file is not renamed? If required, I can also provide full logs of the compile process, they are, however, quite long.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer. I corrected some spelling errors, missed them when writing...

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's due to the nature of your source or indeed your TeX system (which is quite standard), but rather something to do with your system. Have your for example checked the permissions on the location of the `.tex` file?

Comment: @JosephWright seems you are right. The project file is located on a network drive. I however have full access on the drive, and it worked before at the exact same location. If I however copy the project to a local drive (e.g. Desktop), the .synctex file is generated and everything works as expected. Are there known problems regarding .synctex generation on network drives?

Comment: @waza-ari At work we have some network drives where there can be a delay or 'pause' is access. That causes me issues with some tasks (not TeX but I don't have large documents to process on the mapped drive). My guess is you are seeing a similar thing: there's a timing issue in writing to the network drive.